# sharepoint calendar security

Tags: security, sharepoint, calendar

How can I display a calendar in SharePoint that behaves like my Outlook calendar?  I know I can link the calendar to outlook, but anyone can make changes to my calendar in Sharepoint.  How can the Sharepoint calendar enforce security on the calendar so that nobody can override my changes?

Comment: This is not a question for SO,  maybe serverfault, probably superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 2007, there is an option to configure item-level permissions if you go to your **List Settings -> Advanced Settings** page.

In the **Item-Level Permissions** section, under **Edit access: Specify which items users can edit**, select "Only their own".

That should take care of it for you.